# Can I create a program to fill in blanks on a website for windows I already have open?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to purchase multiple of something that i think will sell out in less than a minute. The item will go on sale at X time. I want to already be logged into the website, refresh the page when the item actually goes on sale so that i can add it to the cart, then I want to essentially start my program (Or have my program running in the background and it activates when it notices I now have items in my cart) to finish the checkout process which requires you to manually select your shipping address from a drop down menu, manually select your payment type from a drop down menu, manually enter the security code for my CC, manually select shipping option, and then click review, then submit before processing the order. I am hoping to place 5-6 orders, but having to do all that manually I will be lucky to get even 1 or two placed before the sell out. This would need to be done in multiple browser windows at the same time.

I have been messing around with selenium, but I can only get this to initiate the window and fill out information on that window. I am not sure if it is possible to have selenium initiate the window and log into the site, then wait for me to add the items to the cart and press checkout, and then it continue on.

I have done a little googling and can't seem to find something to do what i'm looking for. I am still new to python and working on my skills. I am just asking for a point in the right direction for a package that this is possible, and maybe someone pointing to a great guide about how the package works so I can try and figure this out.

I will be on a Mac using Chrome incognito windows. I can run this on a PC running windows 10 in incognito windows if necessary.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess, you use some testing tools like [sikuli](http://www.sikulix.com/). Take a look at it.

Comment: @Alperen I will look into this! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Alperen  What i am initially seeing is that Sikuli is going to take control of my mouse essentially and can only really do one task as a time.  I am looking to have say 10 browsers opened, already logged in, and one at a time refresh the page, click add to cart, and then click checkout, then have python run the rest on that browser page and fill it out while im doing the same thing on the next browser, and so on and so on....

Comment: Yes, you are right. It takes control of your mouse. I didn't see the "multiple browser windows" part.